# Specify Laravel validation language

Tags: validation, laravel, localization, laravel-5.1

is it at all possible to tell the Laravel validator which language to use for validation?

I have an application which has its text in English, but for some of the forms, I need the validation errors for the fields to be returned in a different language.

I researched a little and found out that I can just use `\App::setLocale('ro')` to set the language of the app and thus the file under `resources/lang/ro/validation.php` will be used for the validation, but I do not want to temper with the `setLocale`. I could, in the worst scenario, temper with it and change the language before the validation and change it back after the validation again, but it doesn't seem like a good solution.

I am looking for something more like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required',
    'short' => 'required',
], 'lang_that_I_set_in_DB');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did figure this out, thanks for giving me pointers!

This is how it looks in Laravel 5.1:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required',
    'short' => 'required',
]);

$validator->getTranslator()->setLocale('ro');

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If a custom validator is an option for you, you can set the locale of the validators translator:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required',
    'short' => 'required',
]);

$validator->getTranslator()->setLocale('ro');

$this->validateWith($validator);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? would getTranslator() be a custom method in my custom validator?

Comment: "Custom validator" just means that you cannot use the `validate()` method directly that is provided by the trait `ValidatesRequests`. `Validator::make()` just returns an instance of `\Illuminate\Validation\Validator`, so you can set the translators locale manually. You can then use `ValidatesRequest::validateWith()` to validate the request with your "custom" Validator instance. I've edited my answer to provide that part.

Comment: I'd also like to mention that this would work different when using Form Request classes.

Comment: I just tried using this, but it seems this was only introduced in Laravel 5.2, I am currently using 5.1, would you know how it would look in 5.1?

Comment: Glad you found a solution!